# CustomFormatToISO DATE FORMAT

Tags: date, format, apache-pig

I am using built in `piggybank.jar` class `CustomFormatToISO` to convert a date to `ISO` type format. 
I do not know which format to use for cases stored in `time.txt`:

```
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:06 +0000 2014)
(Thu Jan 23 10:07:06 +0000 2014)
```

So for example:

```
A = LOAD 'time.txt' as (t1);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  CustomFormatToISO(t1, 'DY MON dd HH24:MI:SS YYYY');
```

gives me obviously an error.

Can someone help me know how to convert it to `ISO` format or to `TIMESTAMP` or other more common type of date format?

Comment: We have built in functions for this. Check the suggested answer and let me know in case of any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We have built in functions for this. Have a look at the links shared in References.

For the use case shared in question, we can use the below pig script.

**Input : a.csv :**

```
Thu Jan 23 10:07:05 +0000 2014
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' AS (date_string:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToUnixTime(ToDate(date_string,'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy'));
DUMP B;
```

**Output : B :**

```
(1390471625)
```

**References :**

1. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date
2. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-unix-time